# Make HTML Input Elements the same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 HTML containers, but because I have span elements followed by a text input (I think this is the issue?), I'm unable to get the content in the containers centered how I want. Is there a way to push the margin or padding in on these elements? Or is there a simpler way. In the JSFiddle, they spans are pretty large, but I'd like them to be around the size of the picture below. I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">text</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='text' readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/oy4u1sm9/4/

[image]

Idealformatting (without the large span element, of course)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `<span>` tags as labels is not best practice as they are inline elements. Try to always use `<label>` tags. Here is your code tweaked to match your desired styling. More comments in the fiddle below.

```
<div class="row mb-5">
  <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
    <label class="h3">TITLE</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
    <label class="h3">TITLE</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made some comments in the code for clarity. Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/hmLpdnqa/

Answer (score 0):

You just included wrong bootstrap file. Try this and see your issue resolved or not.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="container">
    <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" align="center">
        <h2>TITLE</h2> </div>
      <div class="col" align="center">
        <h2>TITLE</h2></div>
    </div> <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <!-- ROW 2 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm" align="center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="text" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm" align="center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="text">
      </div>
    </div> <!-- ROW 2 -->
   
<br>
<div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">text</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='text' readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

</div>
```